# How to implement Auto scale on Memory based metric in EKS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, tomcat, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have a EKS cluster with min 3 and max 6 nodes, Created auto scaling group for this setup, How can i implement auto scale of nodes when spike up/down on Memory usage since there is no such metric in Auto scaling group like cpu.
Can somebody please suggest me clear steps i am new to this setup .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box ASG does not support scaling based on the memory utilization.
You`ll have to use custom metric to do that.

[Here](https://medium.com/@lvthillo/aws-auto-scaling-based-on-memory-utilization-in-cloudformation-159676b6f4d6) is way how to do that.

Have you considered using CloudWatch alarms to monitor your nodes?
The scripts can collect memory parameters that can be used later.

See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/mon-scripts.html) how to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need Step Scaling Policy

- Target Tracking Policy; can be created for metrics where the needed capacity in proportional to the metric eg, if average CPU utilization is near or above the target value ASG will add capacity i.e. scale out.

See Considerations on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-scaling-target-tracking.html

- Step Scaling Policy; is user controlled you create your own cloud watch alarms and decide the action and setup an inversely proportional policy, eg if average free memory is less you will want to scale out and vice versa

Answer (score -1):

You need to deploy cluster autoscaler which will increase or decreased number of nodes for you.

See the [official docs](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler).

Comment: This is fine, I need a way to configure based on Memory metrics

Comment: This is what cluster autoscaler does by default. Additionally, you can set limits at kindler level so that you reserve for example <10% of cpu and memory.

Comment: I dont think so,  In addition to CA we need to explicitly configure our ASG in AWS with metrics, here im unable to set up for Memory as its not avail like CPU metrics.